# correct sintaxis of json with laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, encode, defined

I have a problem with a Controller because I have this code:

```
public function index()
{
    $all = Nodes::all();
    return Response::json($all);
}
```

My problem is that I need realize a count about this response and I don't know how to express this because in the view I have the following error.

> Undefined variable: all (View: C:\xampp2\htdocs\copiaAngus\app\views\nodes\index.blade.php)

PHP

```
foreach ($all as $user)
{
    var_dump($user->id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Response::json($all) as it is not the way of passing data into a view.

Instead, use:

```
return View::make('nodex/index')->with('all', $all);
```

Then in the view your code should work.